# What are the hexagonal jump point walls?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy, Vol 2,

> Space travel is accelerated by passing through jump points.  The jump points are illustrated as hexagon-shaped opening in walls that are comprised of hexagon-shaped pieces.

**What is the back story of the walls?**

Comment: Bullied by bigger, tougher hexagonal walls, they were exposed to hyperjump rays in an experiment gone wrong.